# IntelliJ IDEA auto does not define the data type

Tags: intellij-idea

According to the value entered in the training I followed, it specifies values such as Double, string, any, int and float.

I set the value by hand.

[image]

Image related to education.

[image]

He knows it's Int.

Comment: Does all options enabled in Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints | Kotlin Types and Parameter hints? If yes, what kotlin plugin version do you use? I tried the first code example and String type is inferred.

Comment: I don't know exactly which feature or plugin it belongs to. I enabled a lot of things.

Comment: It can be enabled in Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints | Kotlin | Types -> Show hints for property types.

Comment: I enabled it but it didn't work.

Comment: I disabled the one below and applied it, activated it again and it worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669449/why-is-the-data-type-not-output